# Programming in Android Studio to able the user to give three numbers and save them

Tags: android

in android stuido I would like to code an activity, where the user can input numbers. For, example he types the number to the textfield, click 'OK' button, then the textfield gets clear, he types the second number, than the third, and after they give the third number the program goes to another activity and sayst thanks for the free number. I would like to save the three numbers for further use and have them in an ascending order. How should I do it?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You should do it just like you described. What part of this process are you having trouble with?

Comment: Please show your work and what options you have tried

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Andrii, this is a very vague and general question. To get you pointed in the right direction though, you would want a layout with an number based-editText widget (for the user input). I would then add the button, and then implement OnClickListener for the button so that everytime the button is pressed, it calls a method you will define that will store the value in an array or list (which can be sorted), along with some kind of tracker to keep track of how many numbers have been entered - then clearing the editText field so that another number can be input; on the third number, the method calls the activity via intent or some other way saying "thanks for the free number".

This is all general and it is going to take quite a bit of work and API Guide/DeveloperDocs searching on the Android web site.